# COUNT total of group by mysql

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

This mysql query gives me the number of sales of my products (total and total_staff) grouped by days and hours of the day. I want the sum of *total* and *total_staff* for each product (not grouped by anything, expect by id). Can I do this in the same query?

```
SELECT p.name, p.color, DATE(date_create) as jour,HOUR(date_create) AS h,
SUM(CASE WHEN s.staff=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total,
SUM(CASE WHEN s.staff=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_staff
FROM manifsSubCategories msc
LEFT JOIN products_subCategories psc ON msc.id=psc.manifSubCategory_id
LEFT JOIN sales s ON psc.product_id=s.product_id
LEFT JOIN products p ON psc.product_id=p.id
LEFT JOIN manifsCategories ON manifCategory_id=manifsCategories.id
WHERE manifCategory_id=1 AND s.category_id=1 GROUP BY jour,h ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the other columns :

```
SELECT p.name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.staff=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.staff=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_staff
FROM manifsSubCategories msc
LEFT JOIN products_subCategories psc ON msc.id=psc.manifSubCategory_id
LEFT JOIN sales s ON psc.product_id=s.product_id 
LEFT JOIN products p ON psc.product_id=p.id
LEFT JOIN manifsCategories ON manifCategory_id=manifsCategories.id
WHERE manifCategory_id=1 AND s.category_id=1
GROUP BY p.name
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

BTW - Your `WHERE` clause is wrong. You are filtering by a table for the `LEFT JOIN` , this will turn your join into an `inner join` due to `NULL` comparison.
 Conditions on the right table of a left join should only be placed inside the `ON` clause.

Comment: Thanks! But can I use only the first query, i.e. I want a new column on the right with let's say *all_total* and *all_total_staff* at the end. It dosen't matter if I have the same results on each line.